# Check bindings in company-active-map

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, ubuntu-16.04, key-bindings, completion

I'm having trouble tracking down an issue that has arisen for unknown reasons. I use `company-mode`, and have always used the default bindings in the `company-active-map` for navigating, eg. <kbd>M-n</kbd> to move to the next possible completion.

Now, for unknown reasons when I hit the `Alt` key during an active completion, the completion menu disappears. My normal recourse is to use <kbd>C-h k</kbd> or the like to see what is happening. However, this also causes the `company-active-map` to disappear. I tried starting emacs with `emacs -Q -L ~/.emacs.d/elpa/company-...` and navigating works as expected, so I know the problem lies in my config somewhere.

Can anyone provide a way to see what keys are bound to during company completion?

Thanks

PS. OS Ubuntu 16.04, emacs 27.0.50

Update: I get no problems on Ubuntu 18.04, so I guess it must have to do with an Alt key issue on that OS.

Comment: @phils It's not a dupe, 27 is in the keymap but still exits the company-active-map. I figure it has something to do with ubuntu

Comment: Your question was "how can I see the bindings in `company-active-map`", which is a duplicate.  It would seem that your question and your *problem* were not related, so maybe you want to ask a new question now that you know a bit more about the problem?

Comment: @phils yes, you're right my question is more an ubuntu 16 keybinding issue at this point, so I'll ask at ubuntu exchange if need be. Thnkks